# Set theory, motivating factors

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, motivation

Set theory seems to pop up in many different fields of mathematics. As someone with a CS degree, I've only encountered very basic set theory; dealing with non-specific sets, and their intersections, unions, and complements. Furthermore, this turned out to be useful in logic and probability which are central in a CS degree.

I was wondering, **what are the motivating factors for learning set theory on a deeper level**? Where is it useful, and do you have any good examples of real life problems (I assume they will be vocational problems, and not personal life problems) that can be solved using set theory?

EDIT: It has been correctly pointed out that this is a duplicate. The suggested duplicate simply didn't show up in my searches.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075320/why-do-we-need-to-learn-set-theory/ seems sort of a duplicate. But let me just point out that "real life problems" are rarely solved by set theory *directly*. So if your goal is to cure cancer, or something, then set theory is not something to put on top of your list. If you do intend to do theoretical work in mathematics, however, then set theory is something worth considering.

Comment: Let me also add that the motivation for studying *any* theoretical mathematics cannot be rooted in the need to solve some real life problem. It could be that by trying to solve some real life problem you ran into some mathematics and wanted to understand that better; but theoretical mathematics does not apply to real life, since it's not dealing with objects found in real life. If you want to cure cancer, learn biochemistry; if you want to fix poverty, learn economics; if you want to end hunger, learn agriculture or food engineering.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It seems you are forgetting theoretical physics which applies to real life and requires heavy mathematics, especially hypothetical things like string theory. (I'm not talking about set theory, it's adressed to "any theoretical mathematics")

Comment: Looking forward to brewing discussion between Asaf and user2345215... :)

Comment: @user2345215: I forgot nothing. Theoretical physics is not a direct application of mathematics for solving real-world problems. If we are talking about indirect problems, then we can find all sort of crazy trails starting at set theory and ending at fixing the climate.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - I agree with the duplicate proposal. And your answer to that question was above and beyond what I expected.

Comment: Alec, I'm glad I could help.