# Importance of set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, education

Currently I write an [article about set theory](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mathe_f%C3%BCr_Nicht-Freaks:_Mengenlehre:_Menge) (in German). Therefore I want to answer the question, why students need to learn something about sets. Among other reasons I have currently the following in my text:

- Each concept of mathematics can be represented by sets (e.g. [Dedekind cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut) for real numbers)
- With set theory fundamental questions about mathematics can be answered and investigated (because you can represent each mathematical concept only with sets)

Are those statements true?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075320/why-do-we-need-to-learn-set-theory

Comment: Hint: How do you define a number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we need to learn Set Theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075320/why-do-we-need-to-learn-set-theory)

Comment: @Bumblebee Since it's more than 8 years ago I have made this question let's say "yes". This question can me marked as a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075320/why-do-we-need-to-learn-set-theory